# Image texture has small dark lines

Tags: texturing, image

I have a question about image texture. If I add my image and play around with mapping, something like this happens.There are small darker lines. The lines are not in the image itself. Can anybody help me,what can I do?

[image]

Comment: It's hard to say is there anything plugged in to the normal input, are those your UV seams?

Answer (score 0):

I saw on blender-today, yesterday, someone brought this question up with curved surface low poly artefacts.  Adjust the angle or shape of the poly faces with rotation or sub-divide to see if that helps.